# Latest version of Passenger that still supports ruby 2.3.7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I have a ruby/rails app that is still stuck on ruby 2.3.7 and uses Passenger 5.3.3. I wanted to upgrade the Passenger version to the latest safe/stable version that still works with ruby 2.3.7

I went through the release notes of each 6.x release and noticed this in the 6.0.9 release notes:
https://github.com/phusion/passenger/releases/tag/release-6.0.9

```
ruby:
2.3.8 → removed
2.5.8 → 2.5.9
...
```

"However", even when i installed a more recent version of Passenger (6.0.14), it seemed to work with Ruby 2.3.7, so i'm quite confused about that those release changelogs are talking about when they mention dropping support for older versions of ruby.

NOTE: I did have to set `PassengerDisableAnonymousTelemetry on` in 6.0.14 to resolve a crashing issue.

Comment: Dropping support for an old version does not necessarily mean that a gem will immediately not be able to run on that old version anymore. It might only mean that the maintainers decided that they removed tests that ensure that the software is still compatible with the old version. And in upcoming releases, they might use newer language features that are not available on old versions anymore. But because they officially dropped support for 2.3.8 I would suggest not using newer versions anymore because you might get weird and unexpected compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought i'd post this here since i got confirmation directly from Phusion
that Passenger v6.0.14 is compatible with Ruby 2.3.7